# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined at eval (app.js_+_120_modules:29481)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

I am trying to make a framework7 cordova vue.js application, but i am getting an uncaught typeerror and my web page doesn't show anything.
[This is a screenshot of my console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEIX0.png)

**My store.js code:**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default  new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
    message:'message from vue'
  },
  mutations: {
   
  }
})
```

**My app.js code:**

```js
// Import Vue
import { createApp } from 'vue';

// Import Framework7
import Framework7 from 'framework7/lite-bundle';

// Import Framework7-Vue Plugin
import Framework7Vue, { registerComponents } from 'framework7-vue/bundle';

// Import Framework7 Styles
import 'framework7/framework7-bundle.css';

// Import Icons and App Custom Styles
import '../css/icons.css';
import '../css/app.css';

// Import App Component
import App from '../components/app.vue';
import store from '../pages/auth/store/store';

// Init Framework7-Vue Plugin
Framework7.use(Framework7Vue);

// Init App
const app = createApp(App);
store,
// Register Framework7 Vue components
registerComponents(app);

// Mount the app
app.mount('#app');
```

**Plus while compiling i also get this error :**

```
WARNING in ./src/pages/auth/store/store.js 3:0-7
export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, Fragment, KeepAlive, Static, Suspense, Teleport, Text, Transition, TransitionGroup, callWithAsyncErrorHandling, callWithErrorHandling, camelize, capitalize, cloneVNode, compile, computed, createApp, createBlock, createCommentVNode, createHydrationRenderer, createRenderer, createSSRApp, createSlots, createStaticVNode, createTextVNode, createVNode, customRef, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent, defineEmit, defineProps, devtools, getCurrentInstance, getTransitionRawChildren, h, handleError, hydrate, initCustomFormatter, inject, isProxy, isReactive, isReadonly, isRef, isVNode, markRaw, mergeProps, nextTick, onActivated, onBeforeMount, onBeforeUnmount, onBeforeUpdate, onDeactivated, onErrorCaptured, onMounted, onRenderTracked, onRenderTriggered, onUnmounted, onUpdated, openBlock, popScopeId, provide, proxyRefs, pushScopeId, queuePostFlushCb, reactive, readonly, ref, registerRuntimeCompiler, render, renderList, renderSlot, resolveComponent, resolveDirective, resolveDynamicComponent, resolveTransitionHooks, setBlockTracking, setDevtoolsHook, setTransitionHooks, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, shallowRef, ssrContextKey, ssrUtils, toDisplayString, toHandlerKey, toHandlers, toRaw, toRef, toRefs, transformVNodeArgs, triggerRef, unref, useContext, useCssModule, useCssVars, useSSRContext, useTransitionState, vModelCheckbox, vModelDynamic, vModelRadio, vModelSelect, vModelText, vShow, version, warn, watch, watchEffect, withCtx, withDirectives, withKeys, withModifiers, withScopeId)
 @ ./src/js/app.js 14:0-46 19:0-5

webpack 5.13.0 compiled with 1 warning in 2916 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

I am new at this and i don't know whats wrong, please help me out!

**This is my package.json:-**

```js
{
  "name": "whatssup",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Whatssup",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --config ./build/webpack.config.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js",
    "build-cordova": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build",
    "build-cordova-ios": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build ios",
    "cordova-ios": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova run ios",
    "build-cordova-android": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android",
    "cordova-android": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova run android",
    "postinstall": "cpy ./node_modules/framework7-icons/fonts/*.* ./src/fonts/"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "Android >= 7",
    "IOS >= 11",
    "Safari >= 11",
    "Chrome >= 49",
    "Firefox >= 31",
    "Samsung >= 5"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "dom7": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "framework7": "^6.0.3",
    "framework7-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "framework7-vue": "^6.0.3",
    "skeleton-elements": "^3.3.0",
    "swiper": "^6.4.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vuex": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "cpy-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "ora": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your package.json file

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yess i edited my question and added package.json

Comment: It is confirmed that the console error log can be expressed in text format. In StackOverflow, code or error logs can be represented as text, and if it's worth searching, we'll guide you in writing text. Not an image, see the link below. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [do-not-upload-images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)